# SQL select x number of rows from table based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to select top 3 rows from 4 vendors from a table of products, following this criteria:

1. Must select 4 vendors.
2. Must select top 3 products for each vendor ordered by product rating.

I tried doing something like:

```
select top 12 * product, vendor 
from products 
order by productrating
```

but obvisously that goesn't give me 3 products for each vendor.

The product table has:

```
productid (int), productname (nvarchar(500)), productrating (float), 
vendor (id), price (float).
```

These are the relevant columns.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: try putting in the table schema  you are using to better explain the layout of the table.

Comment: I'm using MS-SQL (2005+)

Comment: The product table has: productid (int), productname (nvarchar(500)), productrating (float), vendor (id), price (float). These are the relevant columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function to get 3 products for each vendor:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vendor order by rating desc) as seqnum
      from products p 
     ) p
where p.seqnum <= 3
```

If you want 4 vendors:

```
select top 12 p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vendor order by rating desc) as seqnum
      from products p 
     ) p
where p.seqnum <= 3
order by vendor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you top 3 Products per vendor. You didn't specify how you're selecting the 4 vendors. That logic could easily be included using the WHERE clause or using a different ORDER BY depending on how you select the 4 vendors.

```
SELECT TOP 12 vnd.Vendor, apl.ProductName
  FROM Vendors vnd
 CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 3 ProductID
          FROM Products prd
         WHERE vnd.ProductID = prd.ProductID
         ORDER BY prd.ProductRating DESC
       ) apl
ORDER BY vnd.VendorName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed list of vendors you would like to query you can use the following approach:

```
SELECT  TOP 3 
        p.ProductID
FROM    Products p
WHERE   p.ProductID IN ( SELECT     v.ProductID
                         FROM       Vendors v
                         WHERE      v.VendorID IN (Vendor1ID, Vendor2ID, Vendor3ID, Vendor4ID)
ORDER BY p.ProductRating DESC
```

You will need to look for a work-around if you have vendor names to select them filtering out by its name but keeping the join coindition trhough its IDs.